# Parsing output from uTorrent Web UI (need suggestions on best practice)

Tags: python

Im trying to make an automation script for everyday usage, now I would like to use this action in uTorrents Web UI http://www.utorrent.com/community/developers/webapi#devs7 . To get the list of files in the downloaded torrent.

A small code just to see how the output works:

```
import sys
from utorrent.client import UTorrentClient

uTorrent = UTorrentClient("secret", "secret", "secret")
hash = sys.argv[1]

if uTorrent:
    read = uTorrent.getfiles(hash)
    for line in read:
        print line
```

And that would output something like this;

> {u'files': [u'BA99812BAF360F1913D6D98ED8219A94176BAD4C',
>   [[u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent.zip', 9596597617L,
>   9596597617L, 2, 0, 2289, True, 164433, 6122, 1920, 816, -1]]],
>   u'build': 28705}

Or for several files:

> {u'files': [u'67B8F560C81233F3A38F859D99D43193C97A17C6',
>   [[u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent1.zip', 39900, 39900, 2, 0, 1, False, -1, -1, -1,
>   -1, -1], [u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent.zip', 10090482895L, 10090482895L, 2, 0, 4812, True, 230676, 6505, 1920, 1080, -1], [u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent.zip',
>   6670336, 6670336, 2, 4811, 4, False, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]], u'build':
>   28705}

Now to the main question; how would one parse the output efficently (extracting only the files) into a list where I can later on loop through the list and do stuff depending on file extention? I've been pulling my hair on this one, not really sure what to do

Answer (score 1):

To get a file list, use this URI

```
http://[IP]:[PORT]/gui/?action=getfiles&hash=[TORRENT HASH]
```

It sends this back :

```
{
    "build": NUMÉRO DE VERSION (entier),
    "files": [
    HACHAGE (chaîne),
    [
    [
    FILE NAME (NOM DE FICHIER) (chaîne),
    FILE SIZE (TAILLE DE FICHIER) (entier, en octets),
    TÉLÉCHARGÉ (entier, en octets),
    PRIORITY (PRIORITÉ)* (entier)   ],
    ...
    ]
    ]
}
```

With your returned sample :

I just do

```
a = {u'files': [u'67B8F560C81233F3A38F859D99D43193C97A17C6', [[u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent1.zip', 39900, 39900, 2, 0, 1, False, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], [u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent.zip', 10090482895L, 10090482895L, 2, 0, 4812, True, 230676, 6505, 1920, 1080, -1], [u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent.zip', 6670336, 6670336, 2, 4811, 4, False, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]]], u'build': 28705}

z = a['files']

f = z.pop()
```

to get a list of lists of files
where the first element is the name

```
f[0][0]

u'This.is.the.file.i.downloaded.with.uTorrent1.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Louis, but I'm already doing this. I just dont know how to parse the output from the API (see OP)